# How to parse this custom log file in Python3

Tags: python, text

The log file is generated by a program written in C++.

Here is the demo log:

```
|Frame:0|NUMBER:0
|Frame:1|NUMBER:1|{INDEX:0|RECT:[11,24][31,43]}
|Frame:2|NUMBER:2|{INDEX:0|RECT:[11,24][31,43]}|{INDEX:1|RECT:[11,24][31,43]}
|Frame:3|NUMBER:0
```

I am trying to read those log files into a list/dict or etc.

Here is the information that I hope to capture from the demo log above:

```
#frame, number, index, rect
[0,     0] 
[1,     1,      0,      11,24,31,43]
[2,     2,      0,      11,24,31,43,  1,   11,24,31,43]
[3,     0]
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using the `re` library.

```py
import re

code_list = []
with open("log_file.log", "r") as f:
    logs = f.readlines()
    for line in logs:
        parsed_line = line.split("|")
        code_dict = {}
        for parse in parsed_line:
            split_line = parse.split(":")
            key = split_line[0]
            if not key:
                continue
            value = re.findall(r"\d+", split_line[-1])
            code_dict[key] = value
        
        code_list.append(code_dict)
```

You will end up with a list of dictionaries (i.e.:`code_list`), each of which contains both the key and the values in each line.

In line 3, you will have two "INDEX - RECT" dictionaries, but you can then split the whole logs list by "Frame" to understand what codes belong to what line (if needed).

If you only wish for the numbers, you can also try:

```py
import re

code_list = []
with open("log_file.log", "r") as f:
    logs = f.readlines()
    for line in logs:
        codes = re.findall(r"\d+", line)
        code_list.append(codes)
```

This approach will give you a list of lists, each of which  contains a single line.

Edit: if you try to loop through a single string other than a file, try:

```py
import re

code_list = []
logs = log_string.split("\n")

for line in logs:
    # <<<business as usual>>>
```

Comment: Thanks to the rapid reply. It seems the code snippet works for the demo file. But `r"\d+"` is a little dangerous since it does not check the prompts(i.e.: `Frame`, `NUMBER` and etc). How do you think about it?

Comment: @John , have you tried my first approach or only the second one? I believe my first approach solves this issue by labelling each set of codes inside a dictionary, though I may have made a mistake.

Comment: The second one. But the [first one seems not work](https://onecompiler.com/python/3y37ph5jr).

Comment: I see, this is because in your program, you are trying to loop through a string. By doing so, th loop loops through each character, not each line. Try modifying line 13 and also adding a new line before it to first parse the string by lines (string.split("\n")) and then looping through those lines.

Comment: Here is the output: `{'Frame': ['0'], 'NUMBER': ['0']}
{'Frame': ['1'], 'NUMBER': ['1'], '{INDEX': ['0'], 'RECT': ['11', '24', '31', '43']}
{'Frame': ['2'], 'NUMBER': ['2'], '{INDEX': ['1'], 'RECT': ['11', '24', '31', '43']}
{'Frame': ['3'], 'NUMBER': ['0']}`.The code snippet still need to be improved.

Comment: How do you think about my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Juan Facundo Peña.

This answer is base his answer. Which makes some improvement to the duplicate keys.

```
import re

program_result = []

code_list = []
with open("2.log", "r") as f:
    logs = f.readlines()
    for line in logs:
        if line.startswith("|Frame:"):
            parsed_line = line.split("|")
            code_dict = {}
            next_rect_idx_key = ""
            for parse in parsed_line:
                rect_idx = 0
                split_line = parse.strip("{}").split(":")
                key = split_line[0]
                if not key:
                    continue
                data_as_strings = re.findall(r"\d+", split_line[-1])
                data_as_integers = [int(s) for s in data_as_strings]
                if("" != next_rect_idx_key):
                    code_dict[next_rect_idx_key] = data_as_integers
                    next_rect_idx_key = ""
                else:
                    if('INDEX' == key):
                        next_rect_idx_key = key + str(data_as_integers)
                    else:
                        code_dict[key] = data_as_integers

            print(code_dict)
            code_list.append(code_dict)
```